Cannot call method System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_CustomAttributes in this context
An exception is showed when CreateObject("Excel.Application") at run time.
Some times works fine for a short time in the same session, but with code changes the exception occurs in the same session; In most cases, from the first execution with a new session, the exception occurs.
Reviewing various proposed solutions with similar problem, I applied some, for example:
a) Change as automatic in SERVICES:  Install ActivateX  and restarted
b) C:\WINDOWS\system32>regsvr32 scrrun.dll
c) C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow
d) Change project to 32 bits or to 64 bit or Any
but only some times works.
For some reason it fails;  or does not exist, or has another location or what is required to instantiate.
From the above it seems to me to be a Visual Studio bug or error at compile time; I work with VS 2022 community and VB.net
I greatly appreciate the help for a definitive solution to this exception.
Private Sub PreparaXLSX()
   Dim myApp As Excel.Application

   myApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")          

End Sub


System.Exception   HResult=0x80131500  Message = Cannot create ActiveX component.

+ TargetSite    {System.Object CreateObject(System.String, System.String)}  
                System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}

X   Cannot call method System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_CustomAttributes in this context.

What actions to take for a definitive solution or to eliminate access to
System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}

If you're using early binding with Interop:
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Sub PreparaXLSX()
    Dim myApp As Excel.Application
    Try
        myApp = New Excel.Application()
        myApp.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

If you're using late binding without Interop:
Public Sub PreparaXLSX()
    Dim myApp As Object
    Try
        myApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        myApp.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Your suggestion works fine, but if I change my code, the exception occurs again; The problem is intermittent with different solution actions. I appreciate your support Jiachen.

Ensure that you're properly releasing the Excel object when you're done with it. There could be multiple instances of Excel running in the background from previous executions.

ok, thank you;  I have been used routine for kill excel instance.  ¿Are there  other ways to release Excel's instances?

You can explicitly release each Excel COM object (workbooks, worksheets, ranges, etc.) by calling Marshal.ReleaseComObject() for each one. This is a more granular approach to ensure that all references to Excel objects are released.

OK, thanks, I'll be doing
